# Desktop style UI with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

so I'm about to embark on a project where I'll need to use javascript to draw rectangular boxes to represent information (and relationships) in a relational database. Think of a GUI tool like **balsalmiq** or **mysql workbench**. I'll get back a json representation of the data and the relationships and I basically need to draw rectangular boxes where the connection represent the relationships and fill the boxes with data. The data will be finance data, so when for example a security falls by 3%, I need to reflect this. Also a user can update values and these get persisted back.

From my research so far, I'm thinking something like **AngularJS/EmberJS** can be used as the view layer, mixed with some **jquery** for easy dom manipulation. The backend will be done in java, but I'm planning to do a quick pilot in rails because it's so easy to get up and running.

I have a good understanding of JS but haven't done any large scale applications...so your comments, insights or examples are very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at something like ExtJS - you can learn more here http://www.sencha.com/

Comment: Took a look. I've heard of it before. It looks ok, but a little rigid, and prolly corporate. I'm looking at angular + jqueryui and they seem to hold some promise. I'll have to dl and test ExtJs though.